# Council taxes now that I'm moving because I'm changing job

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes

Not sure whom should I ask for this information. I recently got a new permanent job, and I'm moving because I need to stay closer to where I work. Among the stuff that needs to be done there's setting the council taxes apparently. I'm moving into a totally different town and I was used to have "all bill included" and all sort of expenses in my previous renting contract.

Now the question is should my employer in general deducts the council taxes from my salary? Or should I pay it in a different way?

I actually assume my former employer has payed the taxes for me, by deduction. But just for future references I think it's for the best if I know what happens.

Comment: In the UK, the only taxes your employer deducts from your pay are income tax and social security. (And student loan repayments, but they're not a tax).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are buying or renting a home directly (not involving your employer) then you are responsible for paying council tax from your own funds (as distinct from your employer deducting the tax at source)
Contact the Council responsible for your new address and inform them of your moving date. They will send you a bill, which is based on the value of your new home. You can likely do this on the Council website.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "your own funds". I'm not arguing who should pay.

Comment: I think what he meant was that previously, the landlord paid that bill. But the council doesn't care where it gets its money from. The council however does insist that it gets its money. So either you pay it, or the landlord, or whatever arrangement is necessary, so be it. But somebody has got pay it, and at the end of the day, you are the one held responsible.

Comment: Aaah. I'm checking the gov web site. Apparently if I'm a tenant in a room it's the landlord responsible for that. Now I'm living in an apartment by my own, still renting though,  I assume this will count as a house.